# Is there a way to mock a method and not have to mock any calls within that method?

Tags: java, mockito, future

I have a more complicated method ListenableFuture doFoo() that I'm trying to mock and have it return an empty future. However, I'm trying to avoid mocking everything in doFoo since it's a lot of method calls and class variable settings. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, that is typically the purpose of mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Mock the method doFoo() by letting it return the empty future whenever it is called.
Use something like:

```
when(doFoo(*some parameter*)).thenReturn(*empty future*);
```